Why are PEPS more frequently used when simulatind 2D systems rather than branching MERA?
From what I've read it seems that PEPS is a go-to method while simulating 2D quantum systems. Why is it the preferred method rather than branching MERA?
The contraction of PEPS is a #P-complete problem, because of which approximation methods are needed, while the contraction of branching MERA can be performed efficiently. Moreover, branching MERA can support up to volume-law entanglement in more than one spatial dimension, which I guess is not the case with PEPS.
So it seems to me that branching MERA can be at the same time contracted efficiently and is "more powerful" than PEPS. Is there an error in this reasoning? Or rather do PEPS allow for an extraction of some kind of information about the system, for which branching MERA is worse, because of which PEPS gained such popularity?

Optimizing MERA is very hard.

@NorbertSchuch Thank you for the answer! Could you elaborate a bit, or provide some sources with more details? :)

This seems more suited to [scicomp.se] than here.  We don't generally deal with programming related issues here.

@StephenG I wouldn't consider this a programming related issue. Not to mention that tensor networks are not a topic neither on Comp. Science nor matter modeling.

@brzepkowski I don't know sources on the spot, and unfortunately I don't feel like digging out things, sorry. But (i) the scaling of the algorithms in the bond dimension is very bad (you should be able to find this in the literature), and (ii) typically the optimization is much more ill-conditioned (because it is over the unitary group). --- In any case, it should be clear that the optimization is just as important as the contraction, so whatever is harder will be the bottleneck of the method.

Great, thank you very much!

@NorbertSchuch Perhaps convert your comment to an answer.  Even a partial answer is better than no answer.

@StephenG But even a partial answer is there forever. For something which will stay and will be linked to my person, I would like to write something more substantial.
